# The use of Vice from the phrase vice versa

Tags: word-usage

Can vice be used in a sentence in the following way.
"I would recommend using this product, vice, the other one."

Comment: I’d choose this product ***over*** the other one.

Answer (score 6):

No.

There is a preposition *vice*, more common in the 18th and 19th century. It is similar to the prefix *vice* represented in titles like *vice president* and *vice principal*, and means ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice)):

> : in the place of / "I will preside, vice the absent chairman"

Here's another example from the Oxford English Dictionary:

> 1886   C. E. Pascoe London of To-day (ed. 3) xi. 111   It was..soon afterwards reorganized, with Mr. Randegger, vice Mr. Leslie, as conductor.

In both forms, the preposition is preceded by a comma and takes a (usually personal) object.

So you could technically say "I will use this product, vice the other one" to mean you'll use this product *instead of* the other one. However, the preposition has [dropped out of use in the 20th century](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/09/vice-isnt-nice.html) except in military contexts, so there's a high risk of being misunderstood.

Furthermore, *vice* does not serve as an abbreviation of the adverb *vice versa*. In your version of the sentence, *vice versa* [does not make sense as a synonym for "conversely."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice%20versa)

Comment: The railways south of London often run trains made up of 4-car sections, joined together to make 8 or 12 car formations. Sometimes a service is shorter than planned and stations along the route will display hand written notices by the entrance saying e.g. "8.47 to Brighton 8 vice 12" (just that). The seasoned commuters know what it means, but it baffles everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

'Vice' in this sense is not an English word. 'Vice versa' is a Latin phrase. It is accepted as part of English only as the whole phrase, and only because it is understood as a phrase.

(Vice is of course an English word with other meanings, but that's not relevant here.)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you ask, but close.

> **vice**  PREPOSITION  /ˈvʌɪsi/
>
> As a substitute for.
> ‘the letter was drafted by David Hunt, vice Bevin who was ill’

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vice)